# WordPress Protected Page Only Works Once

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a WordPress site that I built for a client a looooong time ago. He has two password-protected pages that have worked fine all the way up until a few days ago.

I've done some troubleshooting and have found that if I set the password and open the page in an incognito tab, the password entry input field displays correctly. I can then enter the password and access the page. Great.

**Here's the kicker**. If I open the page on computer A and computer B the password prompt shows on both computers. If I then enter the password on computer A and refresh computer B, computer B bypasses the password input and the page is shown.

*head exploding emote*

After I reset the password for the pages, no browser/computer can access the page without entering the password. If ANY of the computers/browsers enter the password, every computer/browser now has access.

Has anyone run into this issue before or have any idea where I can begin trying to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I disabled a caching plugin his hosting platform installed for him and it works now. The plugin in question is Breeze by https://www.cloudways.com/en/